# C combination if evaluation of logical operations precedence

Tags: c

I wonder if the following code will always be compiled so that there are no illegal NULL ptr dereferences?

My concern is that the compiler may check if b->value before first checking if "b" is NULL.

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
} mystruct;

int func(mystruct * b)
{
    if((NULL == b) || (b->value == 0))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("value: %d\n", b->value);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the order of evaluation of statements in a if bracket if(...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450585/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-of-statements-in-a-if-bracket-if). Short answer, `||` is evaluated left to right and will short circuit, the details are in the dup listed. Should have been more careful, this is a C question, this is a [better dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)

Answer (score 2):

If `b` is `NULL` then `(NULL != b)` is *false*, then the second side will be checked. (See [Short-Circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) and you might get  NULL ptr dereferences.

Change `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `(NULL != b)` will be tested before `(b->value == 0)`.

What you did is called a [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry, the second condition won't be executed unless the result isn't already determined by the first condition.