# What is the order of evaluation of the statements in this code?

Tags: c, comparison-operators, post-increment

I came across this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int k=8;
int x=0==1||k++;
printf("%d  %d",x,k);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `1  9`.

As this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450585/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-of-statements-in-a-if-bracket-if) suggests that

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

I am unable to understand how the statement `int x=0==1||k++`  is evaluated,due to which the value of x and k becomes 1,9 respectively.

Can someone explain how such statements are evaluated by the compiler in c ?

Comment: It can be written more unambiguously as `int x = ( (0 == 1) || (k++) );` - does that make it clearer?  Which part do you not understand?

Comment: @ OliverCharlesworth why it can't be written as `int x =(0==(1 || (k++))) `  ?

Comment: There are exactly two statements in this code (one expression-statements and one return-statement). They are evaluated top to bottom: first `printf("%d  %d",x,k);` then `return 0;`. The two other lines are declarations, not statements.

Comment: Because `==` has higher precedence than `||`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated."*

yes it's true ...

**to make it clear** *first make sure that* you are aware of these basics

**1) (1 || any_var) is 1**

**2) Operator precedence is as follows**

++

then

==

then

||

**NOW** coming to your doubt of **|| vs |**

**note that** | (single pipe) operator  ..,will execute both LHS and RHS , no matter what)

whereas

|| (double pipe) evaluates LHS of || first and if it is 1 it need not evaluate RHS (for speed)

**RHS of || operator will not be evaluted if LHS comes out to be true**.

**but** here 0==1 is false i.e  0==1 returns 0

**hence** RHS will be evalauted

so the statement

k++ is executed

but 8 is used   (as property of post increment operator says--> first use then increment)

so 0||8 is definitely true (1) so x evaluates to 1

and **then k is incremented** after sequence point ie k is made equal to 9

hence output x=1 and k=9

I hope it clears your doubt :)

Comment: I still don't get you.
Why is 0||8 true?

Comment: @VatsalSura - What else would it be?

Comment: @VatsalSura Because 8 is not zero, hence `||` treats it as "true", and returns 1 for the result.

Comment: @vatsal  by true I mean 1 ...,yeah  ( ! 0 || x) is always 1 , anything other than 0 when ORed with anything turns out to be 1

Comment: So, why the value of `x` is `1` and not `8` or `9`?

Comment: @ vatsal why do you think it should be 8 .. , forget about 9 for now , k is not yet incremented so it wont be 9 at all ..,

NOW as I already commented that as per OR (||) oprerator ,  anything other than 0 when ORed with anything returns 1

Comment: @VatsalSura the `||` operator always gives either 0 or 1

Comment: Ok, Thank you guys, now I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

The Operator || (OR) evaluates to true in the cases:

ex: A || B

- A is true,
- B is true,
- Both are true

Because this operation uses [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) if A is evaluated to true, it means that the statement is true already and it won't evaluate B.

In your case 0==1 (0 equals 1) is clearly false, so it will evaluate k++. k++ is a tricky one (in my opinion). In the world of C true/false evaluation is based on being 0 or not (except for the times false means less than 0...) but in true/false evaluation 0 is false, everything else is true.

K++ means evaluate K then increment, so, **if K is 0 it will be false** and become 1, **if it is anything else, it will be true** and then increment.

In your case k == 8 so the result of k++ is TRUE and k will become 9. K being true means x evaluation resulted in TRUE (it was FALSE OR TRUE).

So the output is 1(True) 9(8++)

Answer (score 1):

`x` is 1 because the expression: `0==1||k++` turns out to be true (which is `1` in C land). Why you ask? There are two sequence points here: `0 == 1` and `k++`. Since the first sequence point evaluates to false (`0` in C land), the second sequence point is evaluated (because the short circuit operator is `||`). The second sequence returns true (or `1`). So, you the entire expression breaks down to: `0 || 1`. Hence `x` is `1`.

`k` is `9` because of `k++`;

HTH.